# CloudTrail logs for Cross-Account Athena queries to remote Glue Data Catalogue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena, amazon-cloudtrail

My AWS account hosts Glue S3 tables in the Glue Data Catalog. We share them with other AWS accounts by using the [Glue Catalog resource policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/cross-account-access.html#cross-account-adding-resource-policy). We do not currently use LakeFormation with this account.

I want to audit who is accessing our Glue Catalog how often, but the CloudTrail events are not useful.

I have tried querying CloudTrail for a variety of ways. The best evidence I can find for interactions with the Catalog Tables is when I look for Glue events:

```
SELECT * FROM "default"."cloudtrail"
where y = '2023'
and m = '11'
and d = '15'
and eventtime like '2023-11-15T08:32%'
and eventsource = 'glue.amazonaws.com';
```

I find interactions taking place for the internal AWS Internal user, but it doesn't show anything about the source account or principle:

```
#   eventversion    useridentity    eventtime   eventsource eventname   awsregion   sourceipaddress useragent   errorcode   errormessage    requestparameters   responseelements    additionaleventdata requestid   eventid resources   eventtype   apiversion  readonly    recipientaccountid  serviceeventdetails sharedeventid   vpcendpointid   tlsdetails  y   m   d
1   1.09    {type=AWSService, principalid=null, arn=null, accountid=null, invokedby=AWS Internal, accesskeyid=null, username=null, sessioncontext=null} 2023-11-15T08:32:59Z    glue.amazonaws.com  BatchGetTable   us-east-1   AWS Internal    AWS Internal            {"catalogId":"123123123123","entries":[{"id":"0","databaseName":"my_db","name":"my_table"}]}        {"insufficientLakeFormationPermissions":["my_db:my_table"],"TableArns":{"0":"arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:123123123123:table/my_db/my_table"},"LakeFormationTrustedCallerInvocation":"true"}  9612333-fb0b-4e09-a009-d012312328c4 3a3fbbaa-6e27-4822-bc6c-b46aab739e4b        AwsApiCall      true    123123123123        011123d0-d4a5-40af-9ed7-b51231235703            2023    11  15
```

Note the Error about LakeFormation. This is strange since the query runs successfully in the recipient account. And we are not making use of LakeFormation in the owner account.

I suspect the CloudTrail logs for this type of Glue sharing and accessing is not being tracked, but I want to see if the community has faced this issue too? Any other clever way of tracking who is interacting with Glue Databases/Tables?